# optim() when optimizing for one parameter in R

Tags: r, function, math, optimization, statistics

I'm trying to find the single value of `scale` in function `bayesmeta::qhalfnormal` such that the first and the second elements of the vector `low_high <- c(.1, 1)` have `.025` and `.975` probability of happening in it, respectively.

In other words, for what value of `scale` .1 can have `.025` and 1 can have `.975` probability.

So, I have one parameter (`scale`) to optimize, and expect a single value for it. I'm using `optim` below but this way, I get two values for `scale`.

Is there a better optimization function to give me a single value for `scale`?

```
library(bayesmeta)


low_high <- c(.1, 1)  
alpha <- c(.025, .975)

f <- function(x) {   
 low_high - qhalfnormal(alpha, scale = x) }

optim(low_high, function(x)sum(f(x)^2))

# $par
> [1] 3.1939758 0.4461607 # I expect a single value for `scale` 
# But it seems `optim()` has acted like `Vectorize(optimize)` looping over 
# elements of `low_high` vector.
```

Comment: I do not think there is a single scale that would make the equation true. Of course you could find an approximate scale. The reason is because the quantiles for the half normal given a specific scale do shift. ie in that the smaller the scale, the larger the quantile for any given probability. In your case, once the scale rises above .4461, then both the probabilities for the quantiles are below .975 and thus cannot be solved. In short there is no solution to your problem. SIMPLY put, think of two parallel lines, where do they intersect? That is what you are trying to solve

Comment: @Onyambu, this very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anonymous.asker is correct that passing a vector of length 2 is confusing `optim()`. What is happening is that `qhalfnormal()` is vectorizing both over the quantiles and the vector of scale values you gave it: e.g. `qhalfnormal(c(0.1, 1), c(0.025, 0.975))` returns a two-element vector comprising (1) the 0.025 quantile for a scale parameter of 0.1 and (2) the 0.975 quantile for a scale parameter of 1. These then get collapsed to a single output value by the sum-of-squares operation ... (what you wanted, I think, was to evaluate `qhalfnormal()` for both quantile levels for a *single* scale parameter).

If you specify a single value that is close enough to the true value you get an answer, and a warning suggesting that you not use Nelder-Mead:

```r
optim(0.45, function(x)sum(f(x)^2))
```

If your starting value is too far from the solution you get a warning *and* an error as soon as the algorithm tries a negative value for the parameter ("scale > 0 is not TRUE").

The sensible way to do this is to specify `method="Brent"` (as suggested by the warning, at which point you also need to specify bounds:

```r
optim(1, function(x)sum(f(x)^2), method="Brent", lower=0, upper=10)
```

This returns 0.4461; this is indeed the argmin (parameter corresponding to the minimum value) for this problem. As @Onyambu points out in comments though, *it doesn't really solve the larger problem* (which is to try to reduce both values to 0); it solves the problem as posed, which is to minimize the objective function ...

Comment: Ben, I guess @Onyambu gave the correct answer (the comment below my post).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a vector of length 2 as the initial estimate. If you want to set bounds for your variable, that's under different arguments in `optim`.